# PyCharm не видит установленные модули на Mac

Tags: python, pycharm, mac, модули

Всем привет! Третий день не могу понять в чем проблема и почему PyCharm не видит модули.

Есть код:

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('Не хочу лишний раз светить ключ', language="ru")

place = input("В каком городе?: ")

observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.get_weather()

temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]

print("В городе " + place + " сейчас " + w.get_detailed_status())
print("Температура сейчас" + str(temp))

if temp < 10:
    print("Сегодня очень холодно, одевайся тепло!")
elif temp < 20:
    print("Холодно, оденься потеплее!")
else:
    print("На улице жара!")
```

pyowm подчеркивается красной полосой

PyCharm ругается и говорит мол:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyowm'**

Скачивал pip через терминал, через команду:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

На что он мне выдает:

```
Processing dependencies for pip

Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

Pyowm устанавливал через команду:

```
pip install pyowm
```

Потом выдает, что все успешно установлено, но я заметил что сверху была надпись:

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.

Кстати говоря, уже много раз устанавливал и переустанавливал Python и среду разработки. Может быть это какой-то конфликт между двумя версиями?

До этого была версия Python 2.7 и при удалении и переустановки все файлы удалялись оттуда.

Был бы невероятно рад если бы кто-нибудь из просветленных смог бы мне помочь с данной проблемой, из-за нее не могу продолжить изучение Python.

На Windows это все работает намного проще и легче, но так уж получилось у меня Mac :(

**Помогите мне пожалуйста, я всегда на связи!**

Comment: что выдает ``pip list``? Какой питон указан в настройках PyCharm?

Comment: DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Package    Version   
  ---------- --------
certifi    2019.3.9   
chardet    3.0.4      
geojson    2.3.0       
idna       2.8        
pip        19.1       
pyowm      2.9.0      
requests   2.21.0     
setuptools 40.6.2     
urllib3    1.24.2      
wheel      0.33.1

Comment: Зачем у вас в 2019 году стоит версия 2.7? И какой питон указан в настройках PyCharm? Подозреваю, что там используется третья версия.

Comment: Я давно по ошибке скачал 2.7 и никак не могу удалить эту версию. В настройках PyCharm в конфигурации указана версия 3.7

Comment: Так Вы сможете мне помочь?

Comment: Помочь удалить 2.7? Нет, не смогу. Но как только удалите, так проблема, скорее всего, и решится. Или настройте в переменных окружения, чтобы использовался пип из третьей версии, а не из 2.7. Не знаю, как это делается в маке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не могу оставить комментарий, поэтому пишу здесь.
Если у вас стоит 2 версии питона(2.7 и 3.х), то устанавливать модули для питона 3 надо через *pip3 install*
Так же возможно вы не установили этот модуль в сам Pycharm. Точно такой же командой в терминале PyCharm'a надо установить модуль *pyowm*

Comment: Спасибо большое, все заработало!